# Custom Data Type rather than using strings

Tags: c#, struct, types

How would I create a custom data type with say 3 options.

```
type pageSize
```

possible values...

```
Small
Medium 
Large
```

I would like to be able for example say my object was called page say...

```
page.size = pageSize.Small
```

up until now I have been just using a string but feel this not ideal.

Comment: Random note regarding C# naming conventions: Types are always written in `PascalCase`, i.e. `PageSize`. Public type members as well, e.g. `Small`, or `Size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [enumerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) for that purpose:

```
public enum PageSize {
  Small, Medium, Large
}
```

You can then have `page.size` declared as a `PageSize` and use exactly what you envisioned:

```
page.size = pageSize.Small
```

If it's only about those options (or potentially about a countable list of other ones) this is fine. However, the actual translation into physical dimensions has to happen somewhere else – and this somewhere else always has to be kept in sync with the enumeration. For page sizes in particular I'd probably opt for something different here:

```
public class PageSize {
  public double Width { get; private set; }
  public double Height { get; private set; }
  public PageSize(double width, double height) {
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
  }

  public static PageSize A4 = new PageSize(210, 297);
  public static PageSize Letter = new PageSize(215.9, 279.4);

  public static PageSize Small = new PageSize(148, 210);
  public static PageSize Medium = A4;
  public static PageSize Large = new PageSize(297, 420);
}
```

This is now an actual data type with properties and a bunch of static predefined values corresponding to the sizes. The advantage here is that you have all predefined sizes defined in the same place and other code doesn't need to care about what `Small` or `Large` means but can just use the measurements.

The drawback here is, though, that you don't have a similarly convenient way of getting all predefined values. With an `enum` you can do

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(PageSize))
```

and bind that to a UI element, e.g. a ComboBox. With static fields in a class you would need to use reflection to do that, which is not as nice.